# Fourier Series simple question

Tags: fourier-series

Let $f$ be a $\mathcal{C}^r$ function such that $f(0)=f(\pi)=0$,
and define $a_n := \frac{2}{\pi}\int^\pi_0 sin(nx)f(x)dx$,
its easy to show that exists $C>0$ such that $|a_n|\leq \frac{C}{n^r}$.
Its possible to find $K>0$ such that $|a_n| \leq \frac{K}{n^{r+1}}$?
In order to do this i only have too bound $\frac{2}{\pi}\int^\pi_0 sin(nx)f(x)dx$ by
some $\frac{K}{n}$ for $f$ continuous. How can i prove this last fact?

Thanks in advance.